# Unable to access controller in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and was wanting to start with the login form. I read a few online materials and decided to give it a go.

Below is my code, and when I click "Login", nothing happens, I am not sure if my html script talks to the controller or did I code something wrong in controller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="loginAuth">
 <head>
  <title>
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <h2>Angular Authentication</h2>

 <div data-ng-controller="loginController">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" data-ng-model="login.username"/>
  <br/>
  
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" data-ng-model="login.password"/> 
  <br/>
  
  <input type="button" ng-submit="login.submit(login.username, login.password)" value="Login"/>
  <br/><br/>
  {{login.message}}
 </div>
 
 <script src="angular.min.js"></script> 
 
 <script>
 
 'use strict';
 
 angular.module('loginAuth')
 .controller('loginController', function ($scope)
 {
 
 function login.submit(username, password)
 {
  if (username === 'admin' && password === 'test99')
  {
   .then(onSuccess);
  }
   else
   {
   .catch(onError);
   }
 }
 
 function onSuccess()
 {
  login.message = 'Login Successful!';
 }
 function onError(reason)
 {
  login.message = reason.message;
 }

 });
  
 </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes to your original code to make it work. Hopefully this will help you learn some Angular :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="loginAuth">
 <head>
  <title>
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <h2>Angular Authentication</h2>

 <div data-ng-controller="loginController">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" data-ng-model="login.username"/>
  <br/>
  
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" data-ng-model="login.password"/> 
  <br/>
  
  <input type="button" ng-click="login.submit(login.username, login.password)" value="Login"/>
  <br/><br/>
  {{login.message}}
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script> 
 
 <script>
 
 'use strict';
 
 angular.module('loginAuth', [])
 .controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.login = {};
 $scope.login.submit = function(username, password)
 {
  if (username === 'admin' && password === 'test99')
  {
   onSuccess();
  }
   else
   {
   onError({message:'login failed'});
   }
 }
 
 function onSuccess()
 {
  $scope.login.message = 'Login Successful!';
 }
 function onError(reason)
 {
  $scope.login.message = reason.message;
 }

 });
  
 </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I see that I had used ng-submit, rather than ng-click for the button event. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You app should be define in proper way.

```
angular.module('loginAuth', [])
```

Also you need to define your controller methods correctly

**Controller**

```
angular.module('loginAuth')
.controller('loginController', function($scope) {
  $scope.login = {};
  $scope.login.submit = function(username, password) {
    if (username === 'admin' && password === 'test99') {
      //.then(onSuccess); //this is something wiered
    } else {
      //.catch(onError); //this is something wiered
    }
  }

  function onSuccess() {
    $scope.login.message = 'Login Successful!';
  }

  function onError(reason) {
    $scope.login.message = reason.message;
  }

});
```

Comment: I had changed my code to look like something below, still am unable to get through the issue

 angular.module('loginAuth', [])
 .controller('loginController', function ($scope)
 {
 
 function login.submit(username, password)
 {
  if (username === 'admin' && password === 'test99')
  {
   login.message = 'Login Successful!';
  }
   else
   {
   login.message = 'Login failed!';
   }
 }

Comment: you have declared function in wrong way..please look at the code which i added in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see the issue, the controller seems to load fine now in the webpage and I don't seethe {{login.message}} bind on screen. But however, the data binding doesnt seem to work upon successful authentication or a failed authentication.

Sorry if am asking too much but I would like to get my understanding right on the basics as I learn them